# Creat Custom Taskpad for SBS2011

Tags: windows-sbs-2011

I'm after a quick guide as to the best way of creating a custom admin type Taskpad for an SBS2011 setup. I have a user who needs to be able to just do some basic user admin ie create a new user, delete a user, reset a password and I don't want to give him access to the SBS 2011 server.

All desktops on the network are Win7 Pro so I'm guessing RSAT needs to be installed onto the desktop first?

Answer (score 2):

I have no idea what Taskpad means, but to do this:

- Go into Active Directory Users and Computers
- Create a group and put the user that you want to give control to into that group.
- Right click on the OU that contains the objects that you would like to delegate permissions for and click "Delegate Permission"
- Follow the wizard to grant permissions to the group that you just made.

Then, just install RSAT on the workstation that the user will use to complete these tasks.